# Sending byte array in asp .net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am creating a web api to allow download files through POST. There is no need for UI. I am sending Byte array along with the Filename in a JSON as follows.

```
{
  "FileName": "xxxyyyzzz.pdf",
  "FileType": "Pricing",
  "FileID": 12457,
  "ContentInByteArray": 
  "JVBERi0xLjMNCiXi48QoNCnN0YXJ0eHJlZg0KMjcxNA0KJSVFT0YNCg==",
  "ExceptionMessage": ""
}
```

The File content is actually converted into Byte array and set to `"ContentInByteArray"`. Is this a good approach. Or Do I need any improvisation.

Please suggest.

Comment: It depends what response  do you expect?

Answer (score -1):

You use send `byte[]` array when you need post file or image content or may be token content and handle them at API.

```
 var request = new SomePostRequest
        {
            Id = 1,
            Content = File.ReadAllBytes(filename); // read content file to byte[]
        };

        jsonSerializer.Serialize(bson, request);

        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.server.com")
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));

        var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray());
        byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/bson");

        var result = await client.PostAsync(
                "api/upload", byteArrayContent);
```

Comment: This does not provide any valuable feedback in regards to the question asked.